# Keyboard Missing Strokes

Tags: keyboard, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit for OS, and IE11 64-bit for browser, with Google Chrome on occasion.

This is probably going to be almost impossible to troubleshoot via forum, but here goes nothing.

If I open a web forum (say, carm.org) using IE11, and then I go to respond to someone in a post, if I use the middle-scroll button of the mouse to move up or down in the reply block, and then I start typing, the keyboard *appears* to miss strokes. I say "appears" because I don't know whether it's the keyboard missing or something else happening. Nevertheless, when I type words, sometimes a letter won't appear. It *appears* as though the keyboard is not keeping up with my fingers.

Now, if I use Google Chrome, this doesn't happen. Also, this doesn't happen in this forum, but only on particular forums. Carm.org uses VBulletin software. Honestly, I'm not about to do control experiments to determine all the forum software that this occurs on. I do know that I was on Photoshop Gurus earlier today and it also happened there. Yes, that is also powered by VBulletin software.

I'm just hoping someone has experienced something similar. What could be going on here? My computer has been recently formatted. Anti-virus is up-to-date, as well as keyboard and graphics drivers. I also enabled "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering" in Internet Options for IE11. This problem occurs whether that is disabled or enabled.

Comment: I was able to find this elsewhere. No, this is not me posting that. It appears someone else has experienced this issue and narrowed it down to VBulletin forums.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4f993a65-e8d4-40ee-9ec5-0aca8f26c7df/missing-key-strokes-random-line-breaks-ie11?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: I ran IE 11 with the option -extoff and this problem still occurs. So, it must not be related to 3rd party add-ons since that option disables them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me *exactly*.  We just got a new computer with Windows 8 and IE11.
It was dropping letters, and basic keyboard functions like triple-clicking to select
a whole line, or double clicking on a word didn't work.  Or using the left arrow and
shift to select back on a word, none of that worked.

I did a search and someone mentioned going to Tools> Internet Options> Security and UNchecking "Enable Protected Mode".  I restarted explorer and now the keyboard functions normally. Of course now IE is saying my computer is at risk??  But either that...or use Firefox.  Everything worked fine in that browser.